# Computed Fields in SP2010 with DisplayPattern Possibilities

Tags: 2010, list-view, custom-field-types

There have been a few references on here about how 2010 uses XSL to render fields in list views. I had built several custom Computed fields in 2007 that used the DisplayPattern attribute. This worked great because I could add these fields to a list via the SharePoint Web Services and jquery. **I do not have access to the server!** This was not an issue in 2007, but so far, it seems that I need to have access to the server to accomplish the same goal in SP2010 to create custom rendering XSL which I could do if I had server access. Is there no other way to do this as easily as it was in 2007? Seems like moving backwards for those without server access! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that I can do this by updating the view properties and specifically the Xsl. I did this by adding a rendering template for my custom field, but included the default Xsl templates. I will update this later with a code example.